# "translation" or "single-word-requests"?

Tags: discussion, tags

If I ask which word I should use for an English word, should I use [translation](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) or [single-word-requests](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)?

I understand that two tags are different, since I could ask which Esperanto word I should use describing what I mean, but which tag should I use when I replace the description of the meaning with an English word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it:

- [translation](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) if you want a translation, it is the general tag for when no more precise tag exist
- [single-world-requests](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-world-requests) if you want a translation into **one Esperanto word** (using word-compounding if necessary)